# jQuery loading gif dynamically

Tags: jquery, image, load

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 here and I am trying to load GIF image dynamically and show loading animation while GIF image loads.

So this is my HTML code. Currently it shows a static JPG image. On clicking `.image-button` class I want to display `loading-animation` until GIF image loaded completely and hide `loading-animation` div as loaded gif displays. And if user again clicked link `.image-button`, I want to hide GIF image and show JPG.

```
<div class="image-container">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="image-button">
        <div class="loading-animation hidden"></div>
        <img class="gif-image hidden" src="http://www.example.com/images/empty.gif" gif-data="http://www.example.com/images/my-image.gif" />
        <img class="jpg-image" src="http://www.example.com/images/my-image.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I am noob with complex jQuery stuff. I can do small stuff like hide/show on click but this is beyond me. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g08h5g3e/)

```
$(".image-button").click(function () {
    if ($(".jpg-image").is(":visible")) {
        $(".loading-animation").show();
        var gifImage = $(".gif-image").attr("gif-data");
        $.loadImage(gifImage).done(function (image) {
            $(".gif-image").attr("src", image.src).show();
            $(".jpg-image").hide();
            $(".loading-animation").hide();
        });
    } else {
        $(".jpg-image").show();
        $(".gif-image").hide();
    }
});
```

code for the `loadImage` plugin

```
$.loadImage = function (url) {
    // Define a "worker" function that should eventually resolve or reject the deferred object.
    var loadImage = function (deferred) {
        var image = new Image();    
        // Set up event handlers to know when the image has loaded
        // or fails to load due to an error or abort.
        image.onload = loaded;
        image.onerror = errored; // URL returns 404, etc
        image.onabort = errored; // IE may call this if user clicks "Stop"    
        // Setting the src property begins loading the image.
        image.src = url;    
        function loaded() {
            unbindEvents();
            // Calling resolve means the image loaded sucessfully and is ready to use.
            deferred.resolve(image);
        }    
        function errored() {
            unbindEvents();
            // Calling reject means we failed to load the image (e.g. 404, server offline, etc).
            deferred.reject(image);
        }    
        function unbindEvents() {
            // Ensures the event callbacks only get called once.
            image.onload = null;
            image.onerror = null;
            image.onabort = null;
        }
    };

    return $.Deferred(loadImage).promise();
};
```

---

**EDIT**

Updated for multiple images, [Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jmsuh4sy/3/)

```
$(".image-button").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.find(".jpg-image").is(":visible")) {
        $this.find(".loading-animation").show();
        var gifImage = $this.find(".gif-image").attr("gif-data");
        $.loadImage(gifImage).done(function (image) {
            $this.find(".gif-image").attr("src", image.src).show();
            $this.find(".jpg-image").hide();
            $this.find(".loading-animation").hide();
        });
    } else {
        $this.find(".jpg-image").show();
        $this.find(".gif-image").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @ChamikaSandamal, it working for one image but if I have more images then it does not work. I want to use it on a page where there will be 5-10 more images and each image should be able to work individually. Check here. http://fiddle.jshell.net/jmsuh4sy/2/show/